How to identify the respective package location from CycloneDX SBOM
CycloneDX SBOM shows 'json5' as a component discovered by manifest-analysis using the file package-lock.json. How can I determine the file where this is actually referred to? I want to map 'json5' to the file it is used in. Is that possible with cycloneDX evidence evinse mode?
  "group": "",
  "name": "json5",
  "version": "2.1.1",
  "scope": "optional",
  "purl": "pkg:npm/json5@2.1.1",
  "type": "library",
  "bom-ref": "pkg:npm/json5@2.1.1",
  "evidence": {
    "identity": {
      "field": "purl",
      "confidence": 1,
      "methods": [
        {
          "technique": "manifest-analysis",
          "confidence": 1,
          "value": "/path/gui/nodegui/package-lock.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "SrcFile",
      "value": "/path/gui/nodegui/package-lock.json"
    }
  ]
},

